# Is this ambiguous rule match not supposed to happen?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, operator-precedence

Trying to understand `next-match` I found an example at [xmlplease.com](http://www.xmlplease.com/xmltraining/xslt-by-example/examples/next-match_1.html), but when I try it out myself I get an `Ambiguous rule match for ...`, and I really can't see how it *wouldn't* get that with this example. How is the third template supposed to take precedence before the other two?

Is the example simply wrong, or am I missing something here?

---

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PRODUCTS>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </PRODUCTS>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product">
        <PRODUCT id="{@id}" price="{@price}" stock="{@stock}" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product[@id = 'p2']">
        <PRODUCT id="{@id}" price="{@price * 1.25}" stock="{@stock}" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product|product[@id = 'p2']">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', @name, ' ')" />
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:next-match />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample input**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product id="p1" name="Delta" price="3250" stock="4" />
    <product id="p2" name="Golf" price="1000" stock="5" />
    <product id="p3" name="Alpha" price="1200" stock="19" />
</products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically given your XSLT you have the same match patterns twice, you have `xsl:template match="product"` and `xsl:template match="product[@id = 'p2']"` and then you have `xsl:template match="product|product[@id = 'p2']"` again. That way there are certainly ambiguous matches for all your `product` input elements. So I agree with you, with a stylesheet that has the same match pattern twice on different templates, you will get that error or warning of ambiguity. However the processor can choose to only emit a warning and to take the last of the templates. That is what Saxon 9 does for instance, it says something like

```
Recoverable error
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /products/product[1]
Matches both "element(Q{}product)" on line 14 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
and "element(Q{}product)" on line 8 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
Recoverable error
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /products/product[2]
Matches both "product|product[@id = 'p2']" on line 14 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
and "product[@id = 'p2']" on line 11 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
Recoverable error
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /products/product[3]
Matches both "element(Q{}product)" on line 14 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
and "element(Q{}product)" on line 8 of
  file:/C:/Users/Martin%20Honnen/Documents/xslt/test2014012101.xsl
```

but then writes an output of

```
<PRODUCTS>
    <!-- Delta -->
   <PRODUCT id="p1" price="3250" stock="4"/>
    <!-- Golf -->
   <PRODUCT id="p2" price="1250" stock="5"/>
    <!-- Alpha -->
   <PRODUCT id="p3" price="1200" stock="19"/>
</PRODUCTS>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the transformation engine used by the author is probably configured like that then. Didn't know that was even an option, hehe.

Answer (score 4):

The XSLT 2.0 spec says that it's an error to have two templates with the same precedence and priority that both match the same node, and that's what's happening here. The spec gives a number of options for what should happen (and Saxon has configuration options allowing you to choose various strategies) but if you want your code to be portable and error-free, the best approach is to add explicit priorities to each rule using the priority attribute on xsl:template. (Higher number means higher priority).